# Переключение раскладки

Tags: c#

Переключение раскладки клавиатуры

Нашёл такой способ:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

А как определить какая в данный момент ?

Comment: Ну так просто читайте это свойство.

Comment: так и определяйте `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage`. Разве название свойства не говорит само за себя?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getCurrentInputLanguage() {
   InputLanguage myCurrentLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
   MessageBox.Show("Current input language is: " +
       myCurrentLanguage.Culture.EnglishName);
}
```